# Where is Jenkins Pipeline script stored and can I control it?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Several tutorials I'm referencing to learn about Jenkins Pipeline scripting guide one to create Jenkins Pipeline jobs as follows:

1. Click `New Item` in the left pane.
   [image]
2. Click `Pipeline` and enter an item name.
   [image]
3. Fill out the little `Pipeline` textbox with your script.
   [image]

**Question: where does this script physically reside?** I don't see anywhere to save a filename -- am I creating `foo.sh` or `/path/to/bar.py` or `/somewhere/../else/baz.pl`? **What is the filename and realpath of the script that I type out in that tiny little text box?**

**Question: is it possible to control the name/location of the Pipeline script that I type in that textbox?** E.g. can this script be something version-controlled in some git repo? And specifically, when this job has no build triggers. I can't help but feel that anonymous script edited in that tiny little text box might be limiting for larger and more complicated scripts.

Sorry for the multiple questions; I've tried to limit them and keep their scope all related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news, is that you absolutely don't have to use that little box to manage your pipeline script.

Jenkins also allows you to [source your Jenkinsfile from an SCM repository like GitHub](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#defining-a-pipeline-in-scm), and will even let you automagically import branches as separate jobs with separate Jenkinsfiles per branch using [multibranch pipelines](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/#creating-a-multibranch-pipeline).

Pipeline scripts are in a language known as Groovy, not Perl or sh or similar. The definitive guides to Groovy are (of course) [the Jenkins reference guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) and [the Groovy reference guide](http://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html).

Comment: Thank you! Seems so obvious now...I think I was confused because the choices that appear when you choose `Pipeline script from SCM` looked nearly identical to something elsewhere related to the source code of the project issuing a generic webhook...I probably did an awful job explaining that, but thank you: this makes sense now, where previously it didn't.